# PHP: Downloading 2 Created Text Files As Zip

Tags: php, zip, text-files

I'm trying to create 2 text files which should only be placed in a downloadable zip file.

Twice use of

```
fopen("php://output","w")
```

with

```
header() things
```

works and helps avoiding file creation on server but I end up mixing the two strings to into one downloadable text file.

Here is a local version of creating 2 files in a local directory:

```
$dirname = "C:/texts";
if (!is_dir($dirname)) {
    mkdir($dirname);
}

$myfile = fopen("C:/texts/one".$dateInputted.".txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
fwrite($myfile, $one);
fclose($myfile);

$myfile = fopen("C:/texts/two".$dateInputted.".txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
fwrite($myfile, $two);
fclose($myfile);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ZipArchive plugin of PHP

```
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$zip->open('path/to/zipfile.zip', ZipArchive::CREATE);
$zip->addFile('some-file.pdf', 'subdir/filename.pdf');
$zip->addFile('another-file.xlxs', 'filename.xlxs');
$zip->close();
```

You can find more help here :

http://akrabat.com/php/creating-a-zip-file-with-phps-ziparchive/

http://php.net/manual/en/zip.examples.php